# Cannot set up ORACLE 12c datasource as connection profile in BIRT

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, birt, oracle12c

I'm trying to set up a Connection Profile in Eclipse BIRT to use Oracle 12c. I've already found this [Unable to create Eclipse Data Source to Oracle 12c using 12c jar. However 11g works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29436755/unable-to-create-eclipse-data-source-to-oracle-12c-using-12c-jar-however-11g-wo) and tried to follow but still I've problem :(

What I did was the following:
- select Window -> Preferences -> Data Management -> Connectivity -> Driver Definition
- Pressed "Add" button
- "Vendor Filter" -> "Oracle"
- Selected Oracle Thin Driver 11 
- Assigned a new name "Oracle Thin Driver 12c"
- Updated "JAR list" with location of ojdbc7.jar
- into "Properties" set "Connection URL" to "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//server:1521/db"

When I'm trying to create a new connection profile I do the following:
- Select "Oracle" then "Next"
- Drivers "Oracle Thin Driver 12c" (the one I created)
- the URL is still showing jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:1521:db :(

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked Java Versions .. sometime java and oracle jar version mismatch can interrupt the detection

Comment: @aRise I've only installed Java 1.8 so that should be fine with current driver (as I'm using as well via standard JDBC in BIRT)

Comment: Did u try from regular DataSource setup -> New JDBC Data Source Profile option . ( not from windows -> preference )